# Get current date and time in custom module and save that in database in magento 2

Tags: magento2, date

I wanted to get the current date and time as created_at. I have tried all the ways I found on google but nothing works for me. It showing error while running my module.

```
   use Magento\Framework\View\Result\PageFactory; 
protected $_timezone;
    /**
     * @param \Magento\Backend\App\Action\Context $context
     */
    public function __construct(
        Context $context,
        \Magento\Framework\Stdlib\DateTime\DateTimeFactory $timezone,
        PageFactory $resultPageFactory
    ) {
        $this->_timezone = $timezone;
        $this->resultPageFactory = $resultPageFactory;
        return parent::__construct($context,$resultPageFactory);
    }
public function execute()
    {
        $date = $this->_timezone->gmtDate();
        echo $date; die;
}
```

But when i am using i am getting this error: `Magento\Framework\ObjectManager\Factory\Compiled->create('Neo\Demo\Control...', array()) called at [vendor/magento/framework/ObjectManager/ObjectManager.php:56]`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use below code

```
use Magento\Framework\View\Result\PageFactory; 
protected $_timezone;
    /**
     * @param \Magento\Backend\App\Action\Context $context
     */
    public function __construct(
        Context $context,
        \Magento\Framework\Stdlib\DateTime\DateTime $timezone,
        PageFactory $resultPageFactory
    ) {
        $this->_timezone = $timezone;
        $this->resultPageFactory = $resultPageFactory;
        return parent::__construct($context,$resultPageFactory);
    }
public function execute()
    {
        $date = $this->_timezone->gmtDate();
        echo $date; die;
}
```

[Reference](https://blog.qaisarsatti.com/magento_2/magento-2-current-store-date-time/)

Comment: Thank you Qaisar but i am getting same error: (Magento\Framework\Exception\RuntimeException): Type Error occurred when creating object:

Comment: Delete generated folder

Comment: Do the recompliation

Comment: Thank you Qaisar now its working after deleting generated folder and cache refresh

Comment: @neomai kindly accept the answer. so it will help future readers.

Comment: @QaisarSatti Could you please help on this issue https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/293795/rolled-back-transaction-has-not-been-completed-correctly-while-saving-product