# Rolled back transaction has not been completed correctly while saving product

Tags: magento2, database, products, flat-catalog

We have been facing an issue while saving **products** & **categories** at the admin end we are getting `Rolled back transaction has not been completed correctly`. We are using Magento 2.3.1 EE

[image]

Can anyone help me with the steps to resolve this issue?

Comment: Exception on save. Disabled third-party extension one by one and check

Comment: Also what do your site index configs look like?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have faced similar issue.
When I review all the magento and server logs, I found an error which is caused by a product save after observer.
Here, the product saved but the observer is trying to do a mysql transaction (which is not related to product) which is failing. So the magento is trying to roll back the transaction and failing.
Trying removing all the after save observers and plugings are your first step of debugging.

Comment: Hi Bro. can you help me on this issue https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/318068/magento2-assign-company-name-to-customer-while-placing-an-order

Answer (score 0):

I faced a similar issue saving one product and checked logs.
In my case it was Square Up Extension. I found that from var/log. I deleted the the  Square Id and saved it worked fine. So I can assume the issue is 3rd party module breaking up the saving process.

Answer (score 0):

I have also faced the similar issue but in my case eav attribute of an extension is not created properly or an product save after observer is causing the issue by commenting the event you can check .

Comment: regarding this issue have you found the solution?

Comment: you can check the product save after observer by commenting it .

Comment: Thanks for answering me, But I have found a solution from my end.

Comment: Did you find the solution for it ?

Answer (score 0):

I have found that solution.

The solution is some 3rd party module database table not defined properly `AUTO INCREMENT & PRIMARY KEY.` In my case module is `SMTP Mageplaza & Magefan Magento 2 Blog.` when upgrading the Magento version that time database is not saved properly.

I have checked to disable one-by-one module & check them & got the error. Now it's working fine from my side.