# Save products magento 2.3 give error Rolled back transaction has not been completed correctly

Tags: magento2.3

I recently migrated from magento 1.9.4.5 to magento 2.3.6 then upgraded to version 2.3.7-p2; I imported customers, orders, categories and products with the magento import tool. All went well. Now after some time, having to modify configurable products, I encounter problems with saving after the modifications, the system presents me with the error "**Rolled back transaction has not been completed correctly.**" and I cannot find a suitable solution which then applies to all old imported products.
The exception.log file show this error:

```
main.CRITICAL: Rolled back transaction has not been completed correctly. {"exception":"[object] (Exception(code: 0): Rolled back transaction has not been completed correctly. at /home/.../public_html/vendor/magento/framework/DB/Adapter/Pdo/Mysql.php:310)"} []
```

In practice, for many products, I am forced to recreate the associates, or in extreme cases to totally recreate the product with all the associates.

I need help to solve this problem, could you please indicate a solution?

Comment: i think this link Help to you `https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/293795/rolled-back-transaction-has-not-been-completed-correctly-while-saving-product`

Comment: you need to check first all events which are called after catalog product save and before catalog product save. you have to disable events and check one by one events

Comment: ok, thanks. I try to follow first the question that you have linked and after check the events.. I will let you know.

Comment: Hi @Vital, I found out what the error depends on. It is due to the Best4Mage CPSD extension. In fact when I disabled the extension then the error disappeared.
So now I have to figure out how to resolve, and I think it may be a conflict with another extension, I assume one from Amasty. If you have any suggestions, they would be useful for me.

Comment: Okay great! you need to check any event used on that extension-related product save after the event and check observer related to the product.

Comment: Hello @Joso! are you getting a proper solution?

Comment: Hi, I don’t have solution yet

Comment: you will upload your extension on google docs which creates an issue and give me the link I will check and find the issue in the extension.

Comment: Hi, How can I contact you in PVT?

Answer (score 0):

I have found that solution.

The solution is some 3rd party module database table not defined properly `AUTO INCREMENT & PRIMARY KEY`. In my case module is `SMTP Mageplaza & Magefan Magento 2 Blog.` when upgrading the Magento version that time database is not saved properly.

I have checked to disable one-by-one module & check them & got the error. Now it's working fine from my side.

Comment: Hi, how can I know which table does not have AUTO INCREMENT & PRIMARY KEY set correctly?

Comment: @Joso You can check the 3rd party module database table so you can find them easily.